# PHP rename( ) in large loop

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, rename

I have roughly 400 items in a database, each with 6-8 .jpegs stored in a directory and named by the item's ID (ie. item 1234 ---> 1234_1.jpg, 1234_2.jpg, etc...).
Long story short, I need to change all of the item id's in the database. I'll then need to do the same with the jpegs so they match.

I'm concerned that using the rename() function while looping through the 400 records will result in a timeout, or maybe it's just not the most efficient way to go about it.

Anyone have another solution or tips for going about this?
Thanks in advance!

```
$img_dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/images/items/";

$newID = 3001;

$getItems = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY RAND()");

while ($row = $getItems->fetch()){

$currentID = $row["id"];

// UPDATE TABLE 1
$update = $pdo->query("UPDATE items SET old_id = $currentID, new_id = $newID WHERE id=$currentID");
// UPDATE TABLE 2
$update2 = $pdo->query("UPDATE items_assoc SET item_id = $newID WHERE item_id=$currentID");

// UPDATE JPEGS
if (file_exists($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_1.jpg")){
    rename($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_1.jpg",$img_dir."originals/".$newID."_1.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."650/".$currentID."_1.jpg",$img_dir."650/".$newID."_1.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."220/".$currentID."_1.jpg",$img_dir."220/".$newID."_1.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."100/".$currentID."_1.jpg",$img_dir."100/".$newID."_1.jpg");
}

if (file_exists($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_2.jpg")){
    rename($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_2.jpg",$img_dir."originals/".$newID."_2.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."650/".$currentID."_2.jpg",$img_dir."650/".$newID."_2.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."220/".$currentID."_2.jpg",$img_dir."220/".$newID."_2.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."100/".$currentID."_2.jpg",$img_dir."100/".$newID."_2.jpg");
}

if (file_exists($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_3.jpg")){
    rename($img_dir."originals/".$currentID."_3.jpg",$img_dir."originals/".$newID."_3.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."650/".$currentID."_3.jpg",$img_dir."650/".$newID."_3.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."220/".$currentID."_3.jpg",$img_dir."220/".$newID."_3.jpg");
    rename($img_dir."100/".$currentID."_3.jpg",$img_dir."100/".$newID."_3.jpg");
}

$newID++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about a time out? Have you encountered the problem?

Comment: I just figure that doing 3,000+ renames in one go is bound to produce an error either with php timeout or actually writing to the directory. I have yet to try it, but would love to anticipate catastrophic errors before giving it a crack.

Comment: Which is it, 400 or 3000?

Comment: 400 records with 6-8 photos per record, so 3000

Comment: Show your code first, it sounds like you have not even tried to write it yourself.

Comment: @lagivan : code included. I have no doubt the code is good, I just wonder the consequences of running 3000+ rename() in one go

Comment: Copy the table (`CREATE TABLE tablename_backup AS SELECT * FROM tablename`) and then copy the images (ssh: `cp -r ./imgDir/ ./imgDir_backup/`) and try your script. You will likely find no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 400 records, a timeout isn't likely. (You can call set_time_limit(0) if you really want to, but I doubt it's necessary.) Just be sure to make a copy of your table first so that you don't lose your mapping in the event your rename doesn't go as planned.

Comment: I will for sure make a copy of the table, but am actually more concerned the error will come in the directory of jpegs. Do servers sometimes struggle to execute that type of command that many times over again?

Comment: 400 times? no, not generally. That is a very small amount of operations by OS standards. You are welcome to add sleep() calls if you want to give your file system a breather between renames.

Comment: except that for each of the 400 records, there are potentially up to 12 jpegs to rename. Hence closer to 3000-5000 renames.

Comment: I remain confident that this will be fine. I encourage you to proceed boldly but with a cautious optimism.

Answer (score 0):

**This approach is fine.**

I don't see why you'd  encounter any trouble.

Just do it, and *if* you have a problem, *then* diagnose that.